# "beta user" label behaves inconsistently on Area 51

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, beta-sites

Currently if I open [this page on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) I see that some sites are marked with "beta user" which somehow implies I'm a user on those sites. However both Travel SE and Firearms SE are in beta now and I have an account on both and have some activity on both yet I have that "beta user" mark near Travel SE entry and don't have one near Firearms SE.

[image: beta]

This looks suspicious. Either I should be listed on both or I should not be listed on either of the sites. If there's some clever logic behind who is listed where then a popup hint explaining what that mark means should be displayed.

Comment: What "beta user mark" are you talking about? Not the filled gradient bar that indicates the status of the *site*, right?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps it's only if you participated in the _private_ beta?

Comment: @S.L. Barth: I don't remember to have ever participated in a private beta.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the screenshot (even if it does have a conspicuous lack of freehand circles). I thought that's might be what you meant, but I didn't see that I had one of those for the Philosophy site, which I definitely participated in the private and public betas for (and earned 200+ reputation). I never have really understood how Area 51 worked. It seems to have an entirely different team of designers behind its UI than the main sites, and in my experience, it frequently defies the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you only get the "Beta user" marker if you have 200 or more reputation on that site.

This is consistent with what I see for my own user, and the fact that "Top beta users" list only lists accounts with at least 200 reputation on that site.

(Can't find an official reference for this though, this is guesswork.)

Comment: This is correct right now, but I'll work on a fix.

Comment: @Emmett were you able to get that fix in?  I still see missing tags.

Comment: I'm guessing not ;(